# Can't use available font in xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode

I'm using gnome-terminal 3.28.2 (on an Ubuntu 18.04 computer) with the font 'DejaVu Sans Mono Book'.

In the terminal, the character '' is rendered okay.

But when I use it in a tex document compiled with xelatex, all I get is an empty box even when choosing DejaVu Sans Mono font explicitly.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}  % must be present
% \usepackage{DejaVuSansMono} % this made no difference
\begin{document}
% % blank page without fontspec package

{\fontspec{DejaVu Sans}}  % Now an empty box
\end{document}
```

Why could this be happening?

I did `fc-list` and saw:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf: DejaVu Sans Mono:style=Book
```

So 'Book' is something called a style.

Is it because I need to set the style as well? How can I do that?

I'm using texlive 2020.

(I'm not looking for a math symbol (not sure if that's how they are called) used in the math-mode, but as a unicode character.)

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: are you sure your terminal isn't using a different fallback font for that character? the version of dejavu mono that I have installed doesn't have U+1D7C6 either

Comment: Oh.. Is there way to check that? And how can we see the glyphs available in a font? Is there a tool for that?

Comment: I guess that's ubuntu specific. Found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049093/gnome-terminal-default-font-for-not-supported-characters) that it might be something handled by font-config.

Comment: Use [`albatross`](https://ctan.org/pkg/albatross) on the command-line (it's in recent TeX Live). You simply pass it the code point you're looking for and it lists all fonts containing a glyph for that.

Comment: Thanks. DejaVu Sans Mono is not showing up for  but DejaVu Sans is. So I suppose it isn't there.